# Metodo get no se puede usar en una función

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo esta practica de la u, estoy revisando lo que llevo de determinaRestriccion y este es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehiculo{
private:
    int Placa;
    string Modelo;
    int Annio;
    float Precio;
public:
    void setPlaca(int Pla){
        Pla=Placa;
    }
    int getPlaca(int Placa){
        return Placa;
    }
    void setModelo();
    string getModelo();
    void setAnnio();
    int getAnnio();
    void setPrecio();
    float getPrecio();
    Vehiculo();
    Vehiculo(int, string, int, float);
    ~Vehiculo();
};

int determinaRestriccion(int ultimoDigito, int getPlaca){
    100000<getPlaca()<999999;
    ultimoDigito=getPlaca()%10;
    return ultimoDigito;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {;
    int setPlaca(938207);
    determinaRestriccion(int ultimoDigito, int get Placa());
    return 0;
}
```

Y me sale este error:

> ```
> error: `getPlaca` cannot be use as a function
> ```

Que sucede y que alternativas me podrian servir porque no se me ocurre ninguna

Comment: En la penultima linea en la funcion derminaRestriccion tienes un error en get placa.

Comment: Que es ese error?

Comment: Falta mucho codigo solo mirando main y las funciones declaradas se comprende que alli o falta o sobra codigo.
Te agradeceriamos que reeditaras la pregunta.

Comment: Falta. Lo pare ahí para probar el extractor de dígitos.

Comment: Porfavor edita la pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

igualmente Puede que te interese el uso y la funcion de get en c++.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/array-get-function-in-cplusplus-stl

Comment: Tu código no hay por donde cogerlo... Por favor, revisa la pregunta y pon algo que sea mínimamente coherente. Tal y como está el código, el error que comentas es solamente uno de los varios que salen... y ni tan siquiera es el primero

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No tienes ni idea de un uso básico del lenguaje, y te estás metiendo con objetos... Algo me dice que llevas mal la asignatura.

Answer (score 5):

Este fragmento de código, haría llorar a un unicornio geek y todos los pitufos nerd desearían dejar la programación para dedicarse a la Ikebana.

```
int determinaRestriccion(int ultimoDigito, int getPlaca){
    100000<getPlaca()<999999;
    ultimoDigito=getPlaca()%10;
    return ultimoDigito;
}
```

La función `determinaRestriccion` recibe un argumento llamado `getPlaca` de tipo entero (`int`), una línea después usas dicho entero como si fuese una función:

```
100000<getPlaca()<999999;
//     ~~~~~~~~^^ <------------------------------------- usado como función.
//         \________________ getPlaca es un entero (int)
ultimoDigito=getPlaca()%10;
//           ~~~~~~~~^^ <------------------------------- usado como función.
//               \__________ getPlaca es un entero (int)
```

Dado que un entero no es una función, obtienes el error que describes. Has creído que la función `getPlaca` del objeto `Vehiculo` podía ser llamada sin más, pero dado que pertenece a un vehículo no puedes llamar a dicha función sin una instancia:

```
int determinaRestriccion(int ultimoDigito, Vehiculo &v){
    100000<v.getPlaca()<999999;
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- getPlaca pertenece a Vehiculo.
    ultimoDigito=getPlaca()%10;
    return ultimoDigito;
}
```

Pero para empeorar las cosas, el resultado de la expresión `100000<v.getPlaca()<999999;` se pierde, pues no estás guardando el resultado de la expresión ni usando la expresión para tomar una decisión.

Y rizando el rizo, la expresión no comprueba que la placa esté entre `100000` y `999999` si no que comprueba primero `100000<getPlaca()` que resultará en un booleano (supongamos que tenga valor `true`) que luego se comprobará contra `999999`, resultando en la expresión `true<999999` que siempre será verdadera.

---

Eso sin tener en cuenta que:

1. Asignas mal las variables miembro:

   ```
   void setPlaca(int Pla){
       Pla=Placa;
   }
   ```

   Ahí asignas la variable miembro al parámetro, lo que esperas es lo contrario.
2. La función de lectura de datos, no lee nada:

   ```
   int getPlaca(int Placa){
       return Placa;
   }
   ```

   Esa función recibe un entero y devuelve dicho entero sin haber operado sobre el mismo. Las funciones de lectura de datos no suelen recibir parámetros y suelen ser constantes.
3. No sabes llamar funciones.

   ```
   int setPlaca(938207);
   ```

   Ese código define un entero (`int`) llamado `setPlaca` y le asigna el valor `938207`. Si quieres llamar a `setPlaca` de `Vehiculo`, necesitas una instancia de `Vehiculo`.
4. Esto no se ni lo que es:

   ```
   determinaRestriccion(int ultimoDigito, int get Placa());
   //                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ <---- ¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?¿?
   ```

Comment: Frases celebres de Paper

Answer (score 0):

Pues si no me he liado con tu código el problema es que cuando llamas a la función, hay que especificar una serie de cosas como donde quieres almacenar el valor que devuelve, porque si no, de poco sirve; luego no puedes pasarle como parámetro una declaración de un entero; y ya para el otro parámetro deberías llamar a la función getPlaca(), en lugar de declarar un entero get, y luego no se por que pones Placa() como si fuera una función, supongo que porque lo que querías era llamar a la función getPlaca(), pero recuerda que también le tienes que pasar un parámetro entero.

Para esa pregunta en concreto deberías cambiar esa linea por:

```
Vehiculo v;
int elNumeroQueTuQuieras = 0;
int numeroPlaca = 0;
int x = v.determinaRestriccion (elNumeroQueTuQuieras, v.getPlaca(numeroPlaca));
```

Pero claro eso es solo en cuestión a lo que preguntas, en el resto del código, hay muchos otros errores, como llamar funciones que devuelven valores sin asignar lo que devuelven a nada, o que algunas funciones como la de getPlaca no tiene mucho sentido porque devuelve lo que le pasas sin más.

(https://www.uv.es/sto/cursos/c++/curso95.pdf)  puedes mirarte este manual que recopila los conceptos básicos de c++, sobre todo para que repases las funciones, para que tu mismo veas los errores que cometes.

Comment: La función `getPlaca` no se puede llamar directamente. Necesitas un objeto de tipo `Vehiculo`

Comment: Si cierto, eso también, no me había dado cuenta, pero si, primero creas una instancia y luego puedes llamar a las funciones.